# Header with Rails and Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I just upgraded an app to Rails 3.2 and am starting to use Twitter bootstrap and JQuery. I'd like to build a header with button that dynamically refresh a div on the page, instead of reloading the whole page.

I started to work on the "Feed" link here, but it's not working as I'd like. When I click on the link, it only displays the first alert with the right text, but doesn't display the alert I put in the $.get call.

What am I doing wrong?

In my view:

```
<div id="header" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- brand name -->
        <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>

        <!-- tabs -->
            <ul class="nav tabs">
              <li class="active"><%= link_to "Feed", "/users/#{logged_in_user.id}/feed",  'data-update' => 'wrap .container' %></li>
              <li><a href="#">Discover</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">My Stuff</a></li>
            </ul>


        <!-- dropdown -->
            <ul class="nav pull-right">
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><%= logged_in_user.first_name.presence ? logged_in_user.first_name.capitalize : "Account" %> <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Log out</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>

        <!-- search -->
            <form class="navbar-search pull-right">
              <input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search">
            </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap

// HEADER
$(function() {

    // mark tab as selected and unselect other tabs
    $('.tabs li').click(function(){
        $('.tabs li').removeClass('active');
        $('.dropdown').removeClass('active');

        var url_attributes = $(this).children("a")
        var url = url_attributes.attr('href');
        var update_div = url_attributes.attr('data-update');
            alert(url+" ? "+update_div);

        $.get(url, function(data) {
            alert(update_div);
            $('#'+update_div).html(data);
        }, 'text');

        $(this).addClass('active');
    })

    // unselect tabs when click on dropdown items
    $('.dropdown li').click(function(){
        $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
    })

})
```

In my controller:

```
def feed
...
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html  { render :text => 'YO in HTML' }
        format.js  { render :text => 'YO in JS' }
      end
end
```

Instead of just refreshing the div I want, it refreshed the whole page with the html response.

And for some reason, the logs call the URL twice when I click on the 'Feed' link:

```
Started GET "/users/3/feed" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-09 15:12:48 -0800
Processing by UsersController#feed as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
...
Started GET "/users/3/feed" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-09 15:12:48 -0800
Processing by UsersController#feed as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
```

What's the right way to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prevent the default execution using jquery preventdefault method so that the default a click event is not executed and there wont be a second request to server.

When a web page is rendered browser adds listeners to all the links in the page. That is the default listener. On top of the default listener you had added one more click listener. When you click on the link browser fires both the events causing two request to the server. In your case want only your custom listener to be fired.

Another way to work with these kind of situations is using a custom attribute in the link and using that variable in your jquery code.

```
<li class="active"><%= link_to "Feed", "#", 'data-update' => 'wrap .container', data-url='/users/#{logged_in_user.id}/feed' %></li>

var url_attributes = $(this).children("a")
var url = url_attributes.attr('data-url');
var update_div = url_attributes.attr('data-update');
```

Comment: Using preventdefault is enough (the get request works once I add preventdefault). Can you explain why preventdefault was needed and remove the comment about .laod and I'll accept your answer?